# Sending authenticated ajax from another domain

Tags: ajax, web, cross-domain

Maybe this is not possible...

I have one site, we'll call it `club.com`

And I have another site called `store.com`

I have control of both domains. `club.com` is powered by a Django project, and `store.com` is a shopify site.

If you're a member of club.com, you get a discount on `store.com`

We want to do it so that integration is seamless. No need to enter your club.com credentials to store.com, we want the page to do that for you.

How do I implement this?

I already tried simply putting an ajax call on `store.com` pointing to `club.com`, and it seems to work with one exception: The browser is not sending the proper cookies along with the request, so when `club.com` gets this ajax request it can't authenticate it.

Comment: ajax would be happening in the browser, wouldn't you want discounts to be determined on the server?

Comment: Yes, but we want each page to know if the user is a member, so we can show the discount. There will also be a discount code that will be used when checking out.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) to achieve what you need.